# Variance of a Random Forest

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, machine-learning, variance

I'm reading through Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISL) right now and I'm having trouble with understanding the variance of a random forest. Does anyone know how this variance is derived? What is $\rho$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The quote says $\rho$ is the pairwise correlation, i.e. the correlation between any two of the random variables. In other words $\mathbb E[(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)]=\rho\sigma^2$ when $i \not=j$ and $\sigma^2$ when $i=j$

So if we have $B$ such random variables, the variance of their average is $$\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac1B\sum X_i-\mu\right)^2\right] \\= \frac1{B^2}\mathbb E\left[\sum_i (X_i-\mu)\sum_j (X_j-\mu)\right] \\ =\frac1{B^2} \left((B^2-B)\rho \sigma^2+B\sigma^2\right)\\= \rho \sigma^2 +\frac{1-\rho}{B}\sigma^2$$

Comment: How did you get from the second line of your proof to your third?

Comment: @Eisen You have $\mathbb E[(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)]$ summed over $i$ and $j$ so $B\times B=B^2$ such terms. $B$ of them have $i=j$ and so $B^2-B$ have $i\not=j$.  Then use the first paragraph.